# Issue setting up xUnit with VSCode and .NET Core, how to correctly set it up?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core, xunit

I am trying to set up a project and unit test it with xUnit, coding in C#.
I followed the steps in this guide https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html
But I had an error "The specified framework version '2.0' could not be parsed
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.0'."

To fix this, I tried specifying the runtimeframeworkversion to 2.1.0 as dotnet --version 2.1.200

I now get an error that is unable to find Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App with version (>= 2.1.0) despite what is returned by dotnet --version.

Any help would be apprciated thanks.

```
My current proj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.1"/>
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.1"/>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I am also running OSX High Sierra

Comment: What is the output of `dotnet --version` at Terminal? Don't use "RuntimeFrameworkVersion" unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @LexLi 2.1.200 you're right quite I don't know what I'm doing I just figured if I have 2.1.200 I could try run version 2.1.0

Answer (score 2):

Try install version 2.0.3 and setup config for it.
Also maybe you will need add strings after line `<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.1"/>`:

```
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.msbuild" Version="2.3.1" />
```

I used it for linux and it worked. But it can help you.

Comment: Thanks mate, will try this

Answer (score 0):

I post my own configuration here , maybe it helps.

The project is a Library named `DataStructures` , testing it with Xunit :

The Tests.csproj :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataStructures\DataStructures.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

.
.

The Launch.json([Gist)](https://gist.github.com/parsalotfy/10a466c0681fc14bdd86debee7e9789d) :

```
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Build_DataStructures",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "dotnet",
            "args": ["build"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/DataStructures",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Run_Tests",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "dotnet",
            "args": ["test"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Tests",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

by this configuration you can build and test by pressing F5.